# jQuery slide out issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am having an issue with some jQuery animations. I managed to make my flex sidebars slide in great but I am having some issue with the slide out effects. The slide out function is making the sidebars instantly vanish.

Also, I believe I need the hide() and show() functions because with just min/max-width the sidebars make the flex canvas very tall.

My slide out functions:

```
  $('#close-left').click(function(event){
        $('#left').animate({
            'min-width': '0px',
            'max-width': '0px',
        }, 1250).hide();

    });

    $('#close-right').click(function(event){
        $('#right').animate({
            'min-width': '0px',
            'max-width': '0px',
        }, 1250).hide();
    });
```

I made a quick fiddle that is producing the same issues: https://jsfiddle.net/89s5tsLr/

**Update:** I made a second fiddle showing how the **right** sidebar causes the flex canvas to be way too tall without the hide() function being called.
https://jsfiddle.net/soq6webp/1/

Thanks in advance for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

remove the .hide()

That's what instantaneously making them disappear and messing up your animation.

--
EDIT: After our exchange in the comments I came to the conclusion that given your circumstances, you may not be able to do what you have in mind, so instead what you can do is:

- Slide out animation first
- Then show the content

  ```
      $('#right').show().animate({ css to change here }, {
      duration: 1250,
      complete: function() {
          // once animation is over, run all the code in this block
      }
  ```

Check out this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FrenchMajesty/89s5tsLr/2/)

The 2nd object passed to an animate function is ***options*** and one of these is complete which call the code once the animation is over.

So we animate the text in this anonymous function so that it's called once the animation on the #right div is over.

We do the same on the close button except we hide away our text first, then slide away the div.

(note the changes in the CSS as well)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I believe I need the hide() and show() functions because with just min/max-width the sidebars make the flex canvas very tall.

Comment: @Alex well I created a quick jsfiddle, it doesn't cause any problems with flex canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/FrenchMajesty/89s5tsLr/1/

If removing the hide/show make the canvas very tall then I would need to see the complete code so I can understand where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I removed the hide() function and added some content to the right sidebar. Unfortunately this is what happens: https://jsfiddle.net/soq6webp/1/

Comment: @Alex , Because of the nature of what you're doing I'm not sure if jQuery allows text to remain fixed while the width is moving. 

Hmm... a solution then would be to hide the text while doing the animation, and show it once its over by animating 'opacity' of the <p>

Comment: Hmm indeed. the opacity: 0 animation did pretty much the same thing it was doing. I did however almost get it working with a max-height animation. Not smooth though https://jsfiddle.net/tvkesjrc/

Comment: Okay, I added an overflow: hidden to the right sidebar, I think i'm onto something. https://jsfiddle.net/muzp1f33/

Comment: @Alex Sorry for taking so long to get back to you.

I have updated my answer.